# プログラミングにおける「返す」と「表示」の違い

Tags: プログラミング言語

プログラミングにおける「返す」と「表示」の違いを素人にもわかるように説明をお願いいたします。

Comment: なぜこの質問をするに至ったか（初心者の方に説明をしなくてはいけないがどう伝えてよいかわからない、サンプルコード・書籍等で学習中に記述の意味が理解できなくて困った等）を記載していただけると、有効な回答が得やすくなると思います（可能であれば「何を説明する時に」や「この説明を見ている時に」といった情報があるとより状況がイメージしやすいです）。

Comment: 質問が曖昧で適切な回答が困難な質問です。あなたが知っている「返す」と「表示」の具体例、その疑問が生じるに至った経緯、あなた自身の解釈、などがあれば回答がしやすくなるでしょう。また、javascriptタグがついていますが、javascriptに限定した話ですか、それとも一般論ですか？

Comment: ita_3y様　アドバイスありがとうございます。ちなみに解決しました＾＾
suzukis様　アドバイスありがとうございます。一般論です。nobu666様の回答で解決しました＾＾

Comment: これは案外、プログラミングを知っている人には思いつかない盲点的な質問だなと思いました。予備知識なくインタプリタで最初にプログラミングに触れた人にとっては、返り値と表示値の区別の説明は必要かもしれません。(返り値を利用するようになればすぐ区別できるようになるでしょうけれど。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「返す」とは呼び出し元に結果を返す、です。
例えば`f(x) = 2x+1`という関数があるとすると、`f(1)`は3を返します。
すなわち`ans = f(1)`とすると`ans`には`f(1)`が返した3が代入されます。

「表示」は文字通りの意味で、画面に結果を表示することです。

Comment: この回答が一番よくわかりました＾＾
ありがとうございました＾＾

Answer (score 2):

「返す」は値を返します。
「表示」は値を表示します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました＾＾